# Power calculation help

Tags: power, energy

I have a hardware setup that provides me with power being consumed every second so I get somewhat of a different reading every second. Using these per second readings how do I calculate kwH?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert power readings to energy readings](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/190164/convert-power-readings-to-energy-readings)

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the average of measurements. Assume that is 1 Ws (Watt second)

Than it's a matter of (SI) unit conversion:

k = 1000, H = hour

Assume you have 1 W/s, which is 0.001 kWs.
3,600 seconds in one hour, thus 0.001 * 3600 = 3.6 kWh

Answer (score 1):

If the readings you acquire are in watts then you need to divide by 1000 to convert to kW then accumulate 3600 successive modified readings and the sum total is in kWh. You can think that each reading you get every second is in watt.seconds or kW.seconds.

### Small print

If the values produced by the device are readings of power calculated in a fraction of a second then, there will be inaccuracies. Ideally you need the thing that gives you the number every second to have averaged the power over the whole of that second.

Answer (score 0):

Watt seconds = Volts * Amps * length of sample period in seconds

Kilowatt hours = watt seconds / 1000 watts in 1 kilowatt / 3600 seconds in an hour

You then sum up these slices over the power consumption period your after. If your after the total consumption you have your result.

If your after average consumption. Divide that by the amount of hours you where recording.